# How can I query certain trading days using YQL?

Tags: php, yql

I'm using PHP to build queries in YQL and the Yahoo! Finance API and retrieve historical stock prices. I'm looking for trends over the last 5 trading days (NOT calendar days). The syntax looks like this:

```
select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "YHOO" and startDate = "yyyy-mm-dd" and endDate = "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

This works fine, but the dates are calendar dates, ie if the start date is the Friday before a three-day weekend, I don't get much useful data. Is there:

- Some form of expression I can use in the query to specify this (Google Sheets, for instance, lets you subtract a number of days from a given date, and assumes those dates are trading days), or
- Some external API or calendar I can use to retrieve and insert the correct start date explicitly?

If this is a case of RTM, forgive me, but please link me to TFM, because I can't seem to find it.